# Powermockito giving me a null exception

Tags: java

I am trying to mock some static methods but I am getting the following stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.unibonn.iai.eis.luzzu.semantics.utilities.SPARQLHelper.toSPARQL(SPARQLHelper.java:12)
at de.unibonn.iai.eis.luzzu.semantics.utilities.DAQHelper.getDomainResource(DAQHelper.java:51)
at de.unibonn.iai.eis.luzzu.semantics.utilities.DAQHelper.getCategoryResource(DAQHelper.java:47)
at de.unibonn.iai.eis.luzzu.annotations.QualityMetadataTest.createMockedMetric(QualityMetadataTest.java:211)
at de.unibonn.iai.eis.luzzu.annotations.QualityMetadataTest.<init>(QualityMetadataTest.java:81)
....
```

DAQHelper is a static class which is called from a method which I am currently testing. To keep the story short, I have a method addMetricData(...) which calls getCategoryResource(...) etc.. This getCategoryResource(..) is a public static method which in turn calls getDomainResource (a private static method in DAQHelper). The getDomainResource(...) method calls the static SPARQLHelper.toSPARQL(...) method.

DO you hav an idea why I am having this problem? The test code is the following:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
```

@PrepareForTest({DAQHelper.class, SPARQLHelper.class})
public class QualityMetadataTest extends Assert {

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

private QualityMetric metric;
private Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
private QualityMetadata _testClass;
private Dataset _dataset;

private Resource metricResource = m.createResource("example:mockedMetric");
private Resource categoryResource = m.createResource("example:mockedCategory");
private Resource dimensionResource = m.createResource("example:mockedDimension");
private Resource dimensionProperty = m.createResource("example:hasMockedDimensionProperty");
private Resource metricProperty = m.createResource("example:hasMockedMetricProperty");
private Resource computedOn = m.createResource("example:testing");
private Resource qualityGraphURI;

private Resource categoryURI;
private Resource dimensionURI;
private Resource metricURI;

private boolean parameter;

@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { false } };
    return Arrays.asList(data);
}

public QualityMetadataTest(boolean QualityMetadataExists) throws Exception{
    this.parameter = QualityMetadataExists;
    if (QualityMetadataExists){
        // fill model m with quality metadata
    }

    this.createMockedMetric();

    _testClass = new QualityMetadata(m,computedOn);
    _testClass.addMetricData(metric);
    _dataset = _testClass.createQualityMetadata();
} 
// some test methods
    private void createMockedMetric() throws Exception{     
    metric = mock(QualityMetric.class);
    when(metric.getMetricURI()).thenReturn(metricResource);
    when(metric.metricValue()).thenReturn(0.5);


    mockStatic(DAQHelper.class);    
    PowerMockito.when(DAQHelper.getCategoryResource(metricResource)).thenReturn(categoryResource);
    PowerMockito.when(DAQHelper.getDimensionResource(metricResource)).thenReturn(dimensionResource);
    PowerMockito.when(DAQHelper.getPropertyResource(dimensionResource)).thenReturn(dimensionProperty);
    PowerMockito.when(DAQHelper.getPropertyResource(metricResource)).thenReturn(metricProperty);
}
```

My belief is that once 'when' methods are created, they are created globally and does not really execute the method but just return the result. I might have a misconception there. Do you have any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From [javadoc](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage): `All usages require @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest annotated at class level.` So, it doesn't look like you can use `@PrepareForTest` with `@Parameterized`

Comment: I tried that as well. And it was giving me an Initialisation error. Apart from that, I still need to run parameterised tests :(

Comment: You don't `need to run parameterized tests` you can simply implement multiple tests, one for each case. Post the initialization error.

Comment: The initialisation error is:
`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFReaderFImpl.reset(RDFReaderFImpl.java:82)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFReaderFImpl.<clinit>(RDFReaderFImpl.java:75)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.<clinit>(ModelCom.java:54)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:140)
 at de.unibonn.iai.eis.luzzu.annotations.QualityMetadataTest.<init>(QualityMetadataTest.java:52)
....` Line 52 is:  private Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(); - this is a jena model